# Typescript get array of two columns value in array of objects

Tags: angular, typescript

i have to get array from an array of objects.

Data

```
var result1 = [
    {id:1, name:'Sandra', type:'user', username:'sandra'},
    {id:2, name:'John', type:'admin', username:'johnny2'},
    {id:3, name:'Peter', type:'user', username:'pete'},
    {id:4, name:'Bobby', type:'user', username:'be_bob'}
```

My Code

```
var data = result1.map(x => {x.id,x.type})
```

Expected O/P

```
    var data = [{id:1,type:'user'},
               {id:2,type:'admin'},
               {id:3,type:'user'},
               {id:4,type:'user'}]
```

my code is not returning the expected result. Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure what you're wanting to end up with here. Objects are composed of key-value pairs, for example { '1': 'user' }, where '1' is the key, and 'user' is the value.

Comment: I want to create an array of objects from another array of objects.

Comment: Use `map` with Object `Destructuring`. `var data = result1.map(({id, type}) => ({id, type}));`